# In 'Black House' who is "a young fellow in upstate New York who shows great promise"?

Tags: stephen-king, the-dark-tower

Towards the end of Black House, the foul Charles 'Burny' Burnside is killed by Tyler Marshall. When Mr Manshun, a servant of the Crimson King, finds the body of his former minion...

> He looks back at Burny one last time, without much regret - **there's
>   a young fellow in upstate New York who shows great promise**, and
>   Burny was pretty well played out, anyway.

We're deep into Dark Tower storylines by this part of the book and knowing Stephen's love of references between books, I have to assume this refers to another anti-hero in another story, though not necessarily a Dark Tower story.

Can anyone suggest who that might be?

Answer (score -2):

Jake Chambers? He shows promise and is very important to the Dark Tower Series

Comment: Wasn't Jake from New York city, is New York city "Upstate new york"? I'm not an American and haven't read the books since they were published, but I seem to remember Jake was from the city.

Comment: I don't think Jake was ever shown as having the potential to be a bad guy.

Comment: Hi, can you add some details to your post by editing them in?